# Java Regex to parse data and get required tag details

Tags: java, regex

**My text file**

```
`<product>`

`<label name="hello" id="121"> <title></title> <para></para> </label>`

`<label name="hi" id="122"> <graphics></graphics> <tag></tag> </label>`

`<test> <anchor></anchor> </test>`

`<label name="bye" id="123"> <text></text> <table></table> </label>`

`</product>`
```

**My output should be id=121 and id=123**

```
`<product>`

`<label name="hello" id="121"> <title></title> <para></para> </label>`

`<label name="bye" id="123"> <text></text> <table></table> </label>`

`</product>`
```

i want to get the entire `<label>` value where id=121 and 123 , this is not xml so i cant use DOM or SAX , please help me using java regex

Comment: What do you mean with "entire label value"? Just the numbers or the name="hello" part?

Comment: is it almost xml ? like html ? because you should use an html parser (or better xml parser).

Comment: its not xml , its sgml so we cant use xml or html parser .. any idea about sgml parser ?

Comment: yes i want the entire label value with tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?i)<label[^>]+?id\s*=\s*"(?:121|123)">[\s\S]+?</label>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oN8uU8/2)

Answer (score 0):

**Ideally** you would see if you can manipulate your input to see if you can make it valid XML, HTML or some other language for which parsers exist.

If you cannot do other wise, you can use something like this: `(<label.+?id="121".+<\/label>)` (Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/bO2zF1/1)) to get the line you are after.

This expression will throw the entire line into a regular expression group, which then you can access through your Java code.

Comment: (<label.+?id="121".+<\/label>) This expression is not working if the </label> is in next line ?

Comment: @Karthick: In that case you would need to provide the `DOTALL` flag, which would allow the expression to also go through new line feeds (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Comment: Yes this helped me , thanks .. but when i try to store it in Pattern while (matcher.find()) {
            pgblk = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(pgblk);
            //System.out.println(matcher.appendTail(sb));
            sb=sb.append(pgblk);
            //System.out.println(sb.toString());
}  when i use this and my pattern is (<label.+?id=\"122\".+?</label>) in java i'm getting both 121 and 122...